# My for loop isn't removing items in my array based on condition? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array (moves) of arrays. I want to iterate through my moves array and set a condition for each element. The condition is, if either number in the element is negative, then I want to remove that element from the moves array. The loop does not remove my items correctly. BUT if I run it through the exact same loop twice, then it WILL remove the last element. This makes no sense to me. Using Python 3.6

```
moves = [[3,-1],[4,-1],[5,-1]]
for move in moves:
    if move[0] < 0 or move[1] < 0:
        moves.remove(move)
```

If you run this code, moves ends with a result of [[4,-1]]
But if you run this result through the exact same for loop again, the result is []

I also tried doing this with many more elements and it's just not grabbing certain elements for some reason. Is this a bug with .remove()? This is what I tried...(In this I tried detecting nonnegative number to see if that was part of the issue, it wasn't)

```
moves = [[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1]]
    for move in moves:
        if move[0] < 2 or move [1] < 2:
            moves.remove(move)
```

The result of the above code is

```
moves = [[4, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1]]
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Do not iterate and modify the list you iterate at the same time.

Comment: So then how do I filter the list based on a condition?

Comment: In your 2nd example nothing would beleft as all elements have onne inner element < 2 .. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yoiur 1st example would also not have anything left - as all elements contain 1 eleemnt less then 0

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes I'm aware that that is what is SUPPOSED to happen, but as you can see from the output, that isn't what's happening. That's what the question is about :)

Comment: Usually its better to have a postitive/negative example - where _some_ elements are filtered and _some_ elements pass through the filter - as example. Thats better so nobody suggests `def fn(iterable): return []` as solution ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through a copy of a list. This can be done by adding `[:]` in your for loop list `moves[:]`.

**Input**

```
moves = [[3,-1],[4,-1],[5,-11], [2,-2]]
for move in moves[:]:
    if (move[0] < 0) or (move[1] < 0):
        moves.remove(move)

print(moves)
```

**Output**

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont iterate and modify at the same time.

You can use a list comp or `filter()` to get a list that fits your needs:

```
moves = [[3,1],[4,-1],[5,1],[3,-1],[4,1],[5,-1],[3,1],[-4,1],[-5,1]]

# keep all values of which all inner values are > 0
f = [x for x in moves if all(e>0 for e in x)]

# same with filter()
k = list(filter(lambda x:all(e>0 for e in x), moves))

# as normal loop
keep = []
for n in moves:
    if n[0]>0 and n[1]>0:
        keep.append(n)

print(keep)

print(f) # f == k == keep
```

Output:

```
[[3, 1], [5, 1], [4, 1], [3, 1]]
```

Doku for `filter()` and `all()` can be found at the overview on [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)